# How to Refresh or Update Fragment UI

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am Passing Data through Activity to Fragment using Bundle, Bundle getting it's value from counter, Counter updating it's value base on Thread.

I was able to get data in Fragment but UI of Fragment only Updating on Fragment Transaction, so question is

> **how can i update fragment Ui at Real time**

Code As Follows:

```
    int i=0;
    Sbundle = new Bundle();
    thread = new Thread() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            i++;
                            Sbundle.putString("speed", String.valueOf(i) );


                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();

}
```

Fragment Transaction onclick :

```
 public void onClick(View v) {



               speedFragment = new SpeedFragment();
                speedFragment.setArguments(Sbundle);


                RoboActivity activity = MainActivity.this;
                if (!isFinishing() && !isDestroyed()) {

                    FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, speedFragment);
                    ft.detach(speedFragment).attach(speedFragment).commit();
                }


    }
```

at fragment side:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    mySpeed = bundle.getString("speed");

        }
```

Comment: I suggest to use `LiveData` and `DataBinding` from `Jetpack` [Refer this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/)

Comment: you need to make an interface and update textview value from activity to fragment by that interface

Comment: Tejas , in short u want me to pass data through interface ??

Answer (score 0):

What UI components you fragment have?
if you have for example TextView than just use `yourTextView.setText(mySpeed)`
of course you need to bind the textView before in you `onCreate()` in fragment.
Also remember if you want to update UI elements after you was in other Thread you should call getActivity().runOnUiTnread(new Runnable(){....})

example:

```
private void toggleLoadingIndicator(boolean toShow) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility((toShow ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE));
      }
    });
  }
```

you can use same technique for `TextView.setText()`

Comment: can u send me any example which involves use of   "getActivity().runOnUiTnread(new Runnable(){....})" , that would be helpful

Comment: Not working because Ui component updating on fragment Transaction , i tried recursive Transaction but app crashing

Comment: Where the code with Thread.sleep is happens? in activity or fragment?

Comment: in activity but i make separate thread in fragment (like u mention)

Comment: if you think that the value that you put in bundle will be updated in fragment each time you update it in activity this is not correct.

Comment: i Edited code if u want anything more like output etc ask me

Answer (score 0):

You can directly refresh by `attach` and `detach` method like below ..

```
FragmentTransaction ft = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(f).attach(f).commit();
```

Comment: what changes do i have to make in attach and detach method in fragment class? can u help me more specifically

Comment: do it in your thread run function. Put that code inside in run method.

Comment: not working , same result as before. I Understood logic behind Your code and technically that should be working but i didn't got result.thanks for support.

Comment: it will work. You want to access `i` value using getting method of activity.